# How can i add parent-child group checkbox to on vuetify datatable?

Tags: vue.js, checkbox, vuetify.js, parent-child, group

When i use the vuetify data datable group header feature and
when the top group checkbox is selected, i want the checkboxes below it to be selected as well.

[image]

Here is the code.
https://codepen.io/ersin-g-ven-/pen/LYdeWor?editors=1010

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      item-key="name"
      sort-by="name"
      group-by="category"
      class="elevation-1"
      show-select
      show-group-by
    >
      <template v-slot:[`group.header`]="{items}">
        <th colspan="2">
          <v-checkbox
            v-model="selected"
            :label="items[0].category"
          ></v-checkbox>
        </th>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using of the "v-model" with "watch" has worked for me:

```
<template v-slot:group.header="{group, items}">
  <th colspan="4">
    <v-checkbox 
      :label="items[0].category" 
      :value="group"
      v-model="selected_groups" 
    >
    </v-checkbox>
  </th>
</template>

...

data() {
 ...
 selected: [],
 selected_groups: []
}

 watch: {
   selected_groups(node_new, node_old) {           

      if(node_new.length < node_old.length) {
        let dif = node_old.filter(x => !node_new.includes(x))[0] 
        this.selected = this.selected.filter(item => { return !Object.values(item).includes(dif) })
      } else if (node_new.length > node_old.length) {
        this.items_arr.forEach(item => {
          if(Object.values(item).includes(node_new.at(-1))) {
            this.selected.push(item)
          }
        })
      } else if (node_new.length == node_old.length) {
          return this.selected
      }

    },
    
    selected(selected_new, selected_old) {
    
      if(selected_new.length < selected_old.length) {
        let dif_NODE = selected_old.filter(x => !selected_new.includes(x))[0][this.groupable_col]          
        let arr_NODEs = []
        selected_new.forEach(item => { arr_NODEs.push(item[this.groupable_col]) })
        
        if(!arr_NODEs.includes(dif_NODE)) { 
          this.selected_groups= this.selected_groups.filter(item => item != dif_NODE)
        }
      } else if(selected_new.length > selected_old.length) {
        if(!this.selected_groups.includes(selected_new.at(-1)[this.groupable_col])) {
          this.selected_groups.push(selected_new.at(-1)[this.groupable_col])     
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just came across your post. I think the combination of `v-treeview` with `selection-type="leaf"` can do the trick.
Check the documentation on: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-treeview/#props-selection-type
and see how it works: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/treeview/#selection-type

Comment: It would be helpful to bring the relevant information from those links into your answer to help provide an answer that is specifically geared to respond the question being asked.